# Weird data after std::vector declaration in header file

Tags: c++, vector, header

I have header file where I declare vector od structs:

```
#include <d3d10.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream> 
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


struct bone{
    string name;
    D3DXMATRIX TransformMatrix;
};

class animator
{
public:
    animator();
    ~animator();

    vector <bone> Skeletone;

    void loadXfile(string Filename);
};
```

Everything looks fine but when I try to use **push_back()** in code and debug, the data in **Skeletone** are **unable to read**. This problem doesn't occur when I use this same type of vector but declared locally in function (**tempvecbone**).

```
if (checkChar == ';'){
    tempvecbone.push_back(tempBone);
    Skeletone.push_back(tempBone);
    while (checkChar != '}')checkChar = fileIn.get();
}
```

[Link to screen from debugger](http://picoolio.net/image/xYR)

Anyone knew what's going on?

Comment: Are you debugging the debug build or the release build?

Comment: not related, but you should never use `using namespace std;` in a header file

Comment: Not sure what `D3DXMATRIX` is, but I suspect a [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/10077) problem.

Comment: post the error message. and compiler. etc. don't link to screenshots of code, please, post the code.

Comment: @FredLarson [Do you even Google?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I use debug build.
@Cheers and hth. - Alf, It's a screenshot from debugger and there is no error messages at this point.

Comment: I also have these same problem when I try to use vector<int>

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem, it was caused by "Maximize Speed (/O2)" Optimization in Visual Studio project settings. It can be changed in Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization (Now I set to Disabled).